# Access a specific property in Object.keys adonis.js (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, database, adonis.js

I have a query that returns an array, with Object.key (array) .foreach I am iterating, I want to know the value of a property in specific array.
Example:

```
 Object.keys(arreglo).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(arreglo[key]);
    });
```

The output is:
name: "Pepito",
Surname: "Perez"
I want to know how to get only the value of the surname
I know it will not work but it would be something like:

```
console.log(arreglo[key].surname);
```

Comment: Can you put the output that you are expecting and the value of **arreglo**?

Comment: I can print the entire value of the array, which is
name: "pepito",
Last name: "perez"
I do it with
arrangement [key]
but I want to get only the value of the LastName property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.forEach` on the original array as shown below. You can even extract the fields you are interested using `Array.map`.

```js
// let's assume the arrary you got from your query is in this format
const arreglo = [
  { firstname: "fn1", surname: "ln1"},
  { firstname: "fn2", surname: "ln2"},
  { firstname: "fn3", surname: "ln3"}
];

// you can log `surname` for each entry in the array
arreglo.forEach(v => console.log(v.surname));

// you can use map to transform the array to just have `surname` using array.map()
const surnames = arreglo.map(v => v.surname);
console.log(surnames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are  looking for

```js
const object1 = {
  a: {firstname:"sali",lastname:"mali"},
  b: {firstname:"sali",lastname:"mali"},
  c: {firstname:"sali",lastname:"mali"}
};

Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key){console.log(object1[key].lastname)});
```